# How to read login details from external json file?

Tags: php, json

I am having difficulty to read username and password from external json file. I want to match username and password from user inputs with json username and password.Can anyone help me please? Thanks

my.json

```
[
  {
    "username":"user@email.com",
    "password":"123456"
  },
  {
    "username":"newuser@email.com",
    "password":"98765"
  }
]
```

php codde

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $JSON = file_get_contents("my.json");
        $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                        new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($JSON, TRUE)),
                        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

       foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    
        if($val==$username &&  $val == $password) {
            print "found";
            $_SESSION['signin'] = $username
        
        }
```

Comment: No. Dont do that... like never do that. That's just asking for trouble. Super bad idea. Use a normal authentication workflow with proper credentials management.

Comment: @WesleySmith Thanks for your response. Can u please tell me how to do it with json?

Comment: No. As I've said, that's very poor form and super insecure. I doubt anyone here would help you write that.

Comment: @WesleySmith I appreciate your suggestion but its requirement and this project is not for commercial purpose. Please help me if u can how to login from reading json file data.Thanks

Comment: It's worth mentioning that your project deesnt have to be "commercial" for this to be harmful. Many people use the same credentials for multiple things. Simply storing credentials this way is a security concern in and of itself if ANYONE but you uses it for anything. If they input their "often used" password, you now know what it is as well as anyone else that ever gets access to that json file. Just dont do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### DO NOT USE THIS FOR ANYTHING EVER

That said, **strictly** to show you where you went wrong, this would do what you want. But again, you *shouldnt*

See @Reed's answer for what you *should* do.

```
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $INSECURE_JSON ='[
      {
        "username":"user@email.com",
        "password":"123456"
      },
      {
        "username":"newuser@email.com",
        "password":"98765"
      }
    ]';

    $array = json_decode($INSECURE_JSON, TRUE);

    foreach ($array as $insecure_val) {
        if($insecure_val['username'] == $username 
           && $insecure_val['password'] == $password) {
            print "found";
            $_SESSION['signin'] = $username;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I edited your code to state 'insecure', even though your bold header is quite obvious. No offense if you rollback lol :D

Comment: @Reed not at all, I dig it :)

Comment: @Wesley Thanks  a lot. but when I trying to access external json file  file_get_contents('result.json') its not working.I mean its not printing found on browser and I am getting blank browser.Can u please help?Thanks

Comment: @user3718511 the only way that would happen is if  a) you cant read the json due to permission issues or similar, b) the inputted values are not present together in the json, (ie the credentials dont match)

Comment: I am not getting any error on screen. Just the blank screen only..

Comment: @user3718511 see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bf5fd03807c93c3aaa4943b3dd9b8fe1be5f4052

Comment: ooh. I am wrongly put some username details. Now I have changed it and its working. Thanks a lot Wesley. You have saved my day..

Comment: @user3718511 Happy to have helped, that said, its worth stating again, please dont ever use this code :)

Comment: Yes, I will keep this in my mind. Thanks so much...

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost, storing passwords in plaintext is incredibly insecure & passwords, instead, should be [hashed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Additionally, the file (whether database or JSON) that contains the username/password combinations should be password protected.

Normally, you would login to a `mysql` database via a password, which creates an additional layer of security away from your web-application. An alternate, but probably less secure method would be to [encrypt & decrypt](https://thedebuggers.com/file-encryption-decryption-using-php-extension-mcrypt/) your json file (I only skimmed the code at that link and I do not guarantee their approach is secure). This will work for small data-sets, but will not be viable for large datasets.

All that being said, if you have a single `bad-security.json` file:

```php
$file = __DIR__.'/bad-security.json';
$encryptedContent = file_get_contents($file);
$content = decrypt($encryptedContent, ...); //you'd have to write the decrypt function
$usernamePasswords = json_decode($content,true);

$passwordInput = $_POST['password'];
$emailInput = $_POST['email'];

foreach ($usernamePasswords as $email=>$passwordHash) {
    if ($email!==$emailInput)continue;
    if (password_verify($passwordInput, $passwordHash){
        $_SESSION['userEmail'] = $email;
    }
}
```

Storing passwords would go something like:

```php
$usernamePasswords = json_decode($content,true);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$newPassword = $_POST['newPassword'];
$confirm = $_POST['confirmNewPassword'];
if ($confirm!==$newPassword)return;// or throw an exception or whatever
$passwordHash = password_hash($newPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
//put the $passwordHash into the $usernamePasswords array
$json = json_encode($usernamePasswords);
$output = encrypt($json);
file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/bad-security.json', $output);
```